# Node.js Video Streamming problem on amazon server

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, video-streaming

I'm developing a website where some videos are played.
I used file sistem to stream the videos to the user and I tested it on localhost and it worked (Although it only worked using internet explorer, didn't test chrome tho)

I uploaded the code to an amazon instance but the videos are not working. and using ie to watch the videos it tries to download them instead of play them on the browser.

on the server i have this to stream the videos

```js
router.get('/videoplay/:video_name', isLoggedIn, async (req, res)  => {

    const { video_name } = req.params;
    const folder_path = "./uploads/"

    console.log(video_name);

    const stat = fs.statSync(folder_path + video_name);
    const fileSize = stat.size;

    const range = req.headers.range;
    if(range){
        const parts = range.replace(/bytes=/g,"").split("-");
        const start = parseInt(parts[0],10);
        const end = parts[1] ? parseInt(parts[1],10) : fileSize-1;
        const chunksize = (end-start) + 1;
        const file = fs.createReadStream(folder_path+video_name, {start,end});
        const head = {
            'Content-Range' : `bytes ${start}-${end}/${fileSize}`,
            'Accept-Range' : 'bytes',
            'content-Length' : chunksize,
            'Content-Type' : 'video/mp4'
        }
        
        res.writeHead(206, head);
        file.pipe(res);
    }else{
        const head = {
            'Content-Length' : fileSize,
            'Content-Type' : 'video/mp4'
        }
        res.writeHead(200,head);
        fs.createReadStream(folder_path + video_name).pipe(res);
    }
});
```

and on the browser

```html
  <div class="d-flex" id="wrapper">

    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div class="bg-light border-right" id="sidebar-wrapper">
      <div class="sidebar-heading">Videos </div>
      <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Search..">
        {{#each video_names}}
            <a href="http://localhost:4000/links/watch/{{video_name}}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">{{video_name}}</a>
        {{else}}
            <a>Empty</a>
        {{/each}}
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div id="page-content-wrapper">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <h1 class="mt-4">Video recordings</h1>
        <video width="640" height="480" controls>   
            <source src="http://localhost:4000/links/videoplay/{{video_display}}">
        </video>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->

  </div>
  <!-- /#wrapper -->

  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
  <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Menu Toggle Script -->
  <script>
    $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    });
  </script>
```

On the server i just modified the urls where it says localhost for the ip of the amazon server